# Can't locate certain element. Selenium. Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Filling in form automatically. Can't locate the month options.

This code chooses the day 6 for the day option.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(@value,'06')][1]").click()
```

This code is what I thought would call the 12th month but instead calls 1912 in the year section

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(@value,'12')][1]").click()
```

the link is https://users.premierleague.com/a/profile/register/personal

[image]

All 3 answers are all viable and I flipped a coin to select which answer to accept to avoid bias. Thanks for the help

Comment: On top of doing like in answers, in situations like these I would suggest first selecting by id with `find_element_by_id` and then by xpath to ensure you are only looking inside a specific element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 5 elements with

```
//option[contains(@value,'06')][1]
```

so use `find_elements` first like this :

```
all_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//option[contains(@value,'06')][1]")
```

and then click on whichever you want :-

```
all_elements[0].click() #to click on first element.
```

Also, full code to select date, Month, year using JS would be :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://users.premierleague.com/a/profile/register/personal")
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('ismjs-profile-dob-day').selectedIndex = '2'")
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('ismjs-profile-dob-month').selectedIndex = '12'")
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('ismjs-profile-dob-year').selectedIndex = '4'")
```

if you notice we are using index, so it should select `2nd-December-2018`

**Update 1 :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://users.premierleague.com/a/profile/register/personal")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
day = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ismjs-profile-dob-day"))))
month = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ismjs-profile-dob-month"))))
year = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ismjs-profile-dob-year"))))
day.select_by_value('04')
month.select_by_value('12')
year.select_by_value('2020')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Note that, Using JS is not recommended if the job can be done via Select class, Please see the updated 1 code.

Comment: The Selenium docs specifically state not to mix implicit and explicit waits. The Selenium contributors have said multiple times not to use implicit waits but to instead use `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: @JeffC : yes, I understand, but that has nothing to do with this question. I have edited my answer to remove implicit wait.

Answer (score 1):

There are several dropdowns on that page, each containing multiple options.
To select month option you can use XPath like this:

```
//select[contains(@id,'month')]//option[contains(@value,'12')]
```

To select day you can use similarly

```
//select[contains(@id,'day')]//option[contains(@value,'12')]
```

etc.

Comment: tysm i didnt know you could have 2 contains in the xpath locator

Comment: Xpath is very strong and flexible tool, it has many strategies to locate elements. Much more that you currently familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this task but this by far is the most customizable approach for this issue.

To locate the day:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ismjs-profile-dob-day']/option[text()='6']").click()
```

To locate the month:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ismjs-profile-dob-month']/option[value()='December']").click()
```

To locate the year:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ismjs-profile-dob-year']/option[text()='2015']").click()
```